# Find word in excel

Tags: excel, vba, search

Im trying to find a word in my excel sheet and write the address of that word in a cell (A2).

My code looks like this

```
Sub SampleCelle()

Worksheets("Data").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Formular = "=CELL(""Address"";INDEX($B$2:$AD$2;MATCH($A$1;$B$2:$AD$2;0)))"


End Sub
```

So Im trying to find the address of the word written in A1, but I get

> run time error 438

when I run it. The ";" are due to local language in excel. 
I hope someone can help me figure out how to get past the error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, does the following provide a solution:

```
Sub SampleCelle()
Dim myCell As String

myCell = 'whatever word you're looking for
Set myRange = Worksheets("Data").Range("A:A").Find(myCell, , xlValues, xlWhole, , MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
Cells("A2") = myRange.Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Selection.Formula = "=CELL(""Address"", OFFSET(A2,,MATCH(A1,B2:AD2,0)))"
```